# CKEditor filemanager in python

Tags: javascript, python, flask, ckeditor, file-manager

I'm creating an app using flask (a small python framework) and I'm trying to integrate CKEditor and filemanager (https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager) but I'm not being able to do it.

I've followed the readme, changed the filemanager.config.js to python language, added the urls to ckeditor config but nothing (no new buttons, no browse or upload).

```
    filemanager: filemanager.config.js
    "options": {
        "culture": "en",
        "lang": "python",
        (...)
```

and

```
ckeditor: config.js
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000/static/js/filemanager/index.html'
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/static/js/filemanager/index.html?type=Images&currentFolder=/Image/';
    config.filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/static/js/filemanager/index.html?type=Flash&currentFolder=/Flash/';
    config.filebrowserUploadUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/static/js/filemanager/connectors/php/filemanager.cfm?mode=add&type=Files&currentFolder=/File/';
    config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/static/js/filemanager/connectors/php/filemanager.cfm?mode=add&type=Images&currentFolder=/Image/';
    config.filebrowserFlashUploadUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/static/js/filemanager/connectors/php/filemanager.cfm?mode=add&type=Flash&currentFolder=/Flash/';
```

I really need to be able to browse and upload files in ckeditor/python. Can someone help me please.

Thank you

Comment: You have to show us some code before anyone can try and help

Comment: I meant show us the flask code. Need to see how you are including the editor in your js/html/templates

Comment: I'm just adding ckeditor to an html file (and POSTing the form to flask)`<textarea id="template-content" name="content">{{ content }}</textarea>` and `CKEDITOR.replace('content', {});`

Answer (score 0):

I'm the main Filemanager you mentioned above. As said in the readme file, "**since many changes have been done recently, only PHP and MVC connectors are now available**".

The [release 0.8](https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/releases/tag/v0.8) may work with Python. (I'm even not sure).

If someone here wants to adapt the existing python connector to support FM last version, it would be great for all python community.